# Disable "Purchase" Button in Android in app purchase Activity

Tags: android, button, android-intent

I am working on a in App Purchase Project: Here is a code of In app purchase. When i click on "Purchase Item" Button Google In app purchase Dialog box show and after successful payment i get "Payment IS Successful".

Now i want when payment is success full the "Purchase Item" Button Auto Disable when i open this application.

Here is the code of `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    IInAppBillingService mservice;
    ServiceConnection connection;
    String inappid = "android.test.purchased"; // replace this with your in-app
                                            // product id

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.purchase);

        connection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                mservice = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                mservice = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            }
        };

        bindService(new Intent(
            "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
            connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

        Button purchaseBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.purchase);
        purchaseBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
                    skuList.add(inappid);
                    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
                    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
                    Bundle skuDetails;
                    try {
                        skuDetails = mservice.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                        "inapp", querySkus);

                        int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                        if (response == 0) {
                            ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                            for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                                String sku = object.getString("productId");
                                String price = object.getString("price");
                                if (sku.equals(inappid)) {
                                    System.out.println("price " + price);
                                    Bundle buyIntentBundle = mservice.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), sku, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
                                    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (RemoteException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (SendIntentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1001) {
            String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                    String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } 
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (connection != null) {
            unbindService(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you get result of purchase on `onActivityResult`, so in that code set clickable your  button to false with following code:

```
purchaseBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

you can change background of your button too , that make better visual for disabling button like GrayOut

so your code must be like following:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString(inappid);
                Toast.makeText(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        "You have bought the " + sku
                                + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             // added this two line /////

             purchaseBtn.setEnabled(false);
             purchaseBtn.setBackGroundColor(Color.GRAY);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and define `purchaseBtn` top of your class that you can reach that on this method.

if you want disable button for all time you need save one flag to Share preference or DataBase or Check from internet, i wrote code with SP for you:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("isPurchase",true);
  editor.commit();
```

and in `onCreate` method you need get that to check value:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(etApplicationContext());
  boolean isPurchase = preferences.getBoolean("isPurchase",false);
  if(isPurchase )
  {
    // disable your button
  }
```

Comment: Thanks sir for replying. Now if i again open this application will i get this button disabled?

Comment: see my Edit for disabling after reopen app

Answer (score 0):

> "Purchase Item" Button Auto Disable when i open this application

Means you need to first know item is already purchased or not for disable or enable purchase button.For this use `mService.getPurchases` which return you all the items already purchased by user:

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
```

Now if item is already present in `ownedItems` then disable purchase Button otherwise enable it.

for more information see [Querying for Purchased Items](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

Comment: I have added 

      try {
   Bundle ownedItems = mservice.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(),
     "inapp", null);
   int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
   if (response == 0) {
    purchaseBtn.setEnabled(false);
   }

  } catch (RemoteException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }

on onCreate() method. Now i'm unable to rum my application. I get Error.

Comment: @AnandSingh : which are you are getting ? and try as `for (String key : ownedItems.keySet()) {
    Object value = ownedItems.get(key);
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s %s (%s)", key,  
    value.toString(), value.getClass().getName()));
}`